# Create TChromium instance with code

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, chromium, createinstance, tchromium

I have an issue trying to create Delphi Chromium Embedded instance with code

```
var
  Chromium: TChromium;
begin
  Chromium := TChromium.Create(TcxTabSheet1);
  Chromium.Parent := TWinControl(TcxTabSheet1);
  Chromium.Align := alClient;
  Assert(Assigned(Chromium.Browser), 'HERE! Why Browser is not assigned.');
  ...
end;
```

Seems like Browser property is initialized when

```
procedure TCustomChromium.CreateWindowHandle(const Params: TCreateParams);
```

is called.

Why CreateWindowHandle is not called in my code?

Comment: Because nothing has been done yet that calls HandleNeeded (which will call CreateWindowHandle when none has been assigned yet).

Comment: If you put your comment as an answer I will accept it. Indeed calling explicitly HandleNeeded solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment as an answer:

The reason `Chromium.Browser` is not yet assigned, when the Browser property is initialized from the CreateWindowHandle, is:

Because nothing has been done yet that calls HandleNeeded (which will call CreateWindowHandle when none has been assigned yet)

Comment: Can I add a suggestion: Don't use *Chromium.Parent := TWinControl(TcxTabSheet1);*, use *Chromium.SetParentComponent(TcxTabSheet1);* instead!